# How can I append in Jquery with parent div having a dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic tab panel where everytime a user clicks add button it generates a new tab. So i need to increment the id of the tab-pane then load the data. 
I have it something working with Jquery ui like this

```
$("button#add-tab").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var num_tabs = $("div#tabSequence ul li").length + 1;

        var tpl = $('#tabSeq').html();

        $("div#tabSequence ul").append(
            "<li><a data-toggle='tab' href='#tab" + num_tabs + "' >#" + num_tabs + "</a></li>"
        );
        $("div#tabContent").append(
            "<div class='tab-pane' id='tab" + num_tabs + "'>" + tpl + "</div>"

        );
```

but I will have to use jQuery .load() API so I don't think this will work:

```
 $("div#tabContent").append(
                "<div class='tab-pane' id='tab" + num_tabs + "'>" + tpl + "</div>"
```

and instead trying to do something like this with no success:

```
 $("div#tabContent").append(
            $( 'div .tab-pane #tab" + num_tabs + "').load( "sequenceTemplate.html" )
        );
```

How do I make a jQuery to create dive with ID of num_tabs then load() a div from another file? 
Which all SequenceTemplate.html has is a single div to load dynamically

Comment: `'div .tab-pane #tab" + num_tabs + "'` is wrong. Should be `'div .tab-pane #tab' + num_tabs`

Comment: cool thanks couldnt find how to use a var inside jQuery correctly

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div#tab" + num_tabs + "

Comment: Read again my first comment above... it should be like: `'div .tab-pane #tab' + num_tabs`

Comment: Just as a side question.... why do you use IDs at all? Why do you think that having bunch of IDs could help? - because of referencing a tab to a content?

Comment: Its what i pasted and seems to insert " + num_tabs + " by itself

Comment: That's not possible. Paste again: `$( 'div .tab-pane #tab' + num_tabs)`

Comment: i need styling on the tab-pane which is hard to do if class name dynamically incrementy

Comment: You can always style using CSS `:nth-child(N)`

Comment: $("div#tabContent").append(
           
            $( 'div .tab-pane #tab' + num_tabs).load( "sequenceTemplate.php" )
        );

Comment: That's wrong again. Please concentrate on your quotes. "What quotes do I use to concatenate string and var? What quotes do I use to encompass attributes? How do I (if needed) escape quotes?" Ask your self those questions and you're done.

Comment: nevermind i thought i had cache killer on

Comment: alright thanks a lot dude, still having problems with same content i enter in each div is being displayed in all the tabs now but I will try and see whats going on

Comment: If you create a [mcve] (yes, with the minimal HTML CSS etc to reproduce your issue) I could take a look.

Comment: i see it not appending the sequenceTemplate.html, each tab-pane sharing same tab. Not sure which is best editor to reproduce loading a file and appending it to a Div. This task is tricky because I am creating an email sequence where user can create multiple emails at once but the email editor does not work properly with more then one editor on the page so I thought trying to load it from another file should do the trick but it is not loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#add-tab").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var num_tabs = $("#tabSequence ul li").length + 1;

  $("<li/>", {
    html: "<a>#" + num_tabs + "</a>",
    appendTo: "#tabSequence ul"
  });

  $("<div/>", {
    class : "tab-pane",
    appendTo : "#tabContent",
    load : "http://output.jsbin.com/kivige/1.js"   //you use: "sequenceTemplate.html"
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add-tab">+ Add</button>
<div id="tabSequence"><ul></ul></div>
<div id="tabContent"></div>
```

**[jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/tezocun/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)**